# Sabre Get Return Flights With Bargain Finder Max

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, sabre

I am working on a travel website powered by Sabre SOAP Api.

I have got to the point of populating a list from the BargainFinderMax(BFM) endpoint and also the leg details and so.

Below is my Request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="3.0.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="3.0.0">  
    <POS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">    
        <Source     PseudoCityCode="XXXX">      
            <RequestorID Type="1" ID="1">        
                <CompanyName Code="XX" />      
            </RequestorID>    
        </Source>  
    </POS>  
    <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">    
        <DepartureDateTime>2017-05-18T15:23:03</DepartureDateTime>    
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="YYZ" />        
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR" />    
        <TPA_Extensions>      
            <SegmentType Code="O" />    
        </TPA_Extensions>  
    </OriginDestinationInformation>  
    <TravelPreferences xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">                
        <TPA_Extensions>      
            <TripType Value="OneWay" />    
        </TPA_Extensions>  
    </TravelPreferences>  
    <TravelerInfoSummary xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">            
        <AirTravelerAvail>      
            <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />    
        </AirTravelerAvail>  
    </TravelerInfoSummary>  
    <TPA_Extensions xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">    
        <IntelliSellTransaction>      
            <RequestType Name="50ITINS" />    
        </IntelliSellTransaction>  
    </TPA_Extensions>
```

My Question is, Is There a way to get Return Flights from bargain finder max or should I:

1. Get One Way flights from Bargain Finder Max for Departure Date and book departure flights
2. Get One Way Flights by calling Bargain Finder Max for return and book the return flight for the specified date.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the request for getting Departure and Return Flights From Sabre.

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="3.0.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="3.0.0">
    <POS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <Source PseudoCityCode="XXXX">
                <RequestorID Type="1" ID="1">
                <CompanyName Code="TN"/>
                </RequestorID>
        </Source>
        </POS>
        <OriginDestinationInformation xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" RPH="1">
                <DepartureDateTime>2017-05-19T17:33:49</DepartureDateTime>
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="YYZ"/>
                        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR"/>
                <TPA_Extensions>
                        <SegmentType Code="O"/>
                </TPA_Extensions>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <OriginDestinationInformation xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" RPH="2">
                <DepartureDateTime>2017-05-29T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="LHR"/>
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="YYZ"/>
                    <TPA_Extensions>
                          <SegmentType Code="O"/>
                    </TPA_Extensions>
       </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <TravelPreferences xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
                <TPA_Extensions>
                        <TripType Value="Return"/>
                </TPA_Extensions>
        </TravelPreferences>
        <TravelerInfoSummary xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
                <AirTravelerAvail>
                        <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                </AirTravelerAvail>
        </TravelerInfoSummary>
        <TPA_Extensions xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
                <IntelliSellTransaction>
                        <RequestType Name="50ITINS"/>
        </IntelliSellTransaction>
</TPA_Extensions>

    </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use multiple OriginDestinationInformation nodes in the same RQ in order to request round trips or even more complex flights.

https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max

Comment: it works thanks, so each itinerary is returned under OriginDestinationOption Segment, and the price of each departure and return flights are returned as well. If i want to choose a different return flight other than the one in the same OriginDestinationOption Segment, is this possible?

Comment: Technically it is possible, but not recommended since you will increase your chances of getting a UC returned due to carrier restrictions.

Comment: I figured it out too, I posted a question about it here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43506767/choose-different-return-flight-for-bargain-finder-max-flight)

Comment: Most travel sites give the option to select the departing flight and then to select the return flights right, if i want to implement that using BFM, would that be possible?..how do you inflict price changes in such a scenario. @Bruno

Comment: I'd say in that case that you should search for one-way flights. I don't think it is a good idea to search for round-trips and then break them apart. Some carriers might want you to sell those round trips in that manner so they won't confirm the flights if you break them apart.

Comment: If i should search for a return flight then should i send a discount code in the request?, usually round trips have a cheaper price. Sabre for some reason still hasn't given access to some docs to me yet and this is taking for ever. @Bruno