# Choose different return flight for Bargain Finder Max Flight

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, sabre

I'm developing a travel application powered by Sabre's Soap Api.

I am calling the BargainFinderMax(BFM) endpoint with the Given request

```
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="3.0.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="3.0.0">
    <POS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <Source PseudoCityCode="XXXX">
                <RequestorID Type="1" ID="1">
                <CompanyName Code="TN"/>
                </RequestorID>
        </Source>
        </POS>
        <OriginDestinationInformation xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" RPH="1">
                <DepartureDateTime>2017-05-19T17:33:49</DepartureDateTime>
                        <OriginLocation LocationCode="YYZ"/>
                        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="LHR"/>
                <TPA_Extensions>
                        <SegmentType Code="O"/>
                </TPA_Extensions>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <OriginDestinationInformation xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" RPH="2">
                <DepartureDateTime>2017-05-29T00:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
                    <OriginLocation LocationCode="LHR"/>
                    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="YYZ"/>
                    <TPA_Extensions>
                          <SegmentType Code="O"/>
                    </TPA_Extensions>
       </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <TravelPreferences xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
                <TPA_Extensions>
                        <TripType Value="Return"/>
                </TPA_Extensions>
        </TravelPreferences>
        <TravelerInfoSummary xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
                <AirTravelerAvail>
                        <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
                </AirTravelerAvail>
        </TravelerInfoSummary>
        <TPA_Extensions xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
                <IntelliSellTransaction>
                        <RequestType Name="50ITINS"/>
        </IntelliSellTransaction>
</TPA_Extensions>

    </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

I get the following from the soap response:

1. Two OriginDestinationOption

   a. *One containing flight Segments for the Trip to the destination*

   b. *The other containing the flight Segments for the return trip from the destination.*
2. FarePriceInfo for the each OriginDestinationOption- contains the price of the entire trip (including UpTrip and Return trip)

**Consider the Scenario:**

**OriginDestinationOption: a**

*UpTrip - a*: YYZ - LHR -

*Return Trip - a*: LHR - YYZ

*Total Trip Price = $900*

**OriginDestinationOption: b**

*UpTrip - b*: YYZ - LHR

*Return Trip - b*: LHR - YYZ

*Total Trip Price = $940*

My Question is:

1. if i select *UpTrip -a* for my uptrip, is it possible for me to select *ReturnTrip - b* for the return trip?
2. If no the above question, am I missing any parameters in the request to enable that combination feature.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `AirItinerary` element inside `PricedItinerary` that have the complete itinerary to be booked. It is not recommended to mix legs from different `AirItinerary` elements, because fare rules may not be met.

So, not only there's no guarantee that the price will remain the same, there's no guarantee that the new itinerary will price.

There's no feature that will do what you want, the thing that gets closer is Multi-Ticket. In the [resources page of DevStudio](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/soap_apis/air/search/bargain_finder_max/resources), you have online help documents, specifically, please check on [**this link**](http://files.developer.sabre.com/doc/providerdoc/shopping/BargainFinderMax_Help/BargainFinderMax_Help.htm#Features/MultiTicket/Introduction.htm#kanchor1468).

Comment: Thank you very much. :).